# How to set folder user:group on archlinux makes node could create file

Tags: node.js, permissions, archlinux, usergroups

on archlinux, we have a folder called `/srv` which belongs to `http:users`. In my nodejs code I want to create new file `/srv/my_test/1.log` but result is Permission Denied.

After I changed `/srv/my_test` from `http:users` to `my_username:users`, it worked.

So what's the right way of setting folder permission when my nodejs code need create file on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make `/srv` chowned by `http:users`, check folder permissions are 775 and be sure your user is a member of the users group.

This way:

```
$ chown http:users /srv
$ chmod 775 /srv
```